# spring security defining user registration with ROLE_USER

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am making a project in *Spring MVC* 4 with *Hibernate* and *Spring Security*. In this project I have 3 roles: `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_COMPANY` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.

User will register like regular registration site, but I am confused on how to save a new user in database through registration process, that how to save the new user and database defined by *Spring Security* and how to fetch that information using hibernate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have your `User` class that implements `UserDetails` which has either one or many authorities. For example:

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserAuthority> authorities;


    //helper method to set roles for this user
    public void grantRole(UserRole role) {
        if (authorities == null) {
            authorities = new HashSet<UserAuthority>();
        }
        authorities.add(role.asAuthorityFor(this));
    }

    //overrides, getters, setters
}
```

**UserAuthority**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserAuthority.class)
public class UserAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String authority;

    //overrides, getters, setters
}
```

**UserRole**

```
public enum UserRole {
    USER, COMPANY, ADMIN;
}
```

While creating user just:

```
User user = new User();
user.grantRole(UserRole.USER);
repository.save(user);
```

As for authenticating you need to implement `UserDetailsService` that loads the user from the repository

**UserDetailsService implementation**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    private final AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker detailsChecker = new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker();

    @Override
    public final User loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = repository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        detailsChecker.check(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now in your Security configuration you just use that `UserDetailsService`

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
}
```

How you fetch the data is up to you, I would be using Spring Data JPA for that.

Comment: Its is very good explanation. So when i save the user like when he registers should i use @ModelAttribute of User and give the role in container and save the user, or is there any other standard way to save a spring security User. And also sir i have not yet learned setting security.xml through Annotations. How will i set security.xml in beans. Like how will this change

Comment: <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

Comment: If you're on stage where you're able to switch to Java based configuration then please do it. XML for this is really cumbersome and I would avoid it at any cost if possible. There are now many many tutorials/gits that demonstrate how it can be setup. As for first question, this `User` is like any other entity in your application, persist it how you wish.

Comment: ok sir I will learn Java based configuration. Thank you for your answer, will  query if found any problem.

Comment: Look into Spring Boot, it does most of the things for you. All you have to do is write your own Security class and have the dependencies, Boot will automatically configure basic things for you. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples

Comment: Hello sir can u help me with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715345/spring-mvc-java-based-configuration-not-working-console-display-no-error-but-my