# Spring mvc Java based Configuration not working. Console display no error but my jsp page is not showing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hello i am converting my simple demo project from bean configuration to pure java based configuration. Bean configuration works fine creating tables and all. But my java configuration is not displaying any pages. I solved many errors bur now console shows no error specifying the problem. here's my code please find whats wrong, or have i missed anything in the configuration. I am new to spring and fairly new to java based configuration. These are the sites from which i took code.

http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-tutorial-form-login-java-config/

for hibernate i use used this tutorial

http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/

My classes

```
1. AppConfiguration
 package com.kharoud.configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan({"com.kharoud"})
 @Import({MvcConfiguraion.class, RepositoryConfiguration.class})
 public class AppConfiguration {

 }
```

2.MvcConfigurtion

```
package com.kharoud.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import       org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguraion extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling( DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer ){      
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){      
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;

}
}
```

3.RepositoryConfiguration
    package com.kharoud.configuration;

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){        
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.kharoud.model"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",      environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {        
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new   HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
}
```

4.SpringConfigurationInitializer

```
package com.kharoud.configuration.initilizer;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.kharoud.configuration.AppConfiguration;


public class SpringConfigurationInitializer extends     AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {

    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

only added these new classes. I deleted my web.xml.

Later on i will add Spring Security configuration class

this is my console output

```
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal     performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window     s;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/server;C:/Program   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program     Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\      system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShe     ll\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;;C:\ECLIPSE\eclipse;;.
 Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
 WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ProjectDemo' did not find a   matching property.
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1063 ms
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using  [SHA1PRNG] took [217] milliseconds.
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath:  [com.kharoud.configuration.initilizer.SpringConfigurationInitializer@389ae113]
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger  (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 25, 2015 2:32:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11876 ms
```

MyHomeController

```
package com.kharoud;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Myindex.jsp file is in WEB-INF/views folder under webapp folder

```
The views were properly resolved with bean configuration.
```

Comment: Your `MvcConfiguration` shouldn't be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` but the `DispatcherServlet`. Remove the `AppConfiguration` class and let the correct components load the different configurations.

Comment: Or let the `DispatcherServlet` load all of the configuration instead of the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: i should just delete my AppConfiguration class. How and from where ContextLoaderListener  is loading my MvcConfiguration. Should i initilize all classes through SpringConfigurationInitializer. Can you please give a little code for where to load dispatcherServlet. Thank you

Comment: The `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` takes care of that you just have to pass the correct config classes. Letting the `getServletConfigClasses` return the `AppConfiguration` instead of the `getRootConfigClasses` will probably fix your issue.

Comment: I made the changes but still no effect. I also corrected @Configurable to -@Configuration in my MvcConfiguration class but it also didn't made it work.

Comment: What isn't working, what would you expect? I don't see controllers so nothing is selecting pages. I would also argue that your view resolver configuration is slightly off `/WEB-INF/views` probably needs a closing `/`.

Comment: I have also added my HomeController.

Comment: This is not specific solution but try creating a new project with basic web source. e.g. only one controller,config file, and one jsp page. if it works add other stuff. if u hit problem at the beginning then post that problem.

Comment: a ref gradle project https://github.com/lynas/SpringMvcWithGradle

Comment: yes sir i will make a new project to see if the basic things are working. Will post if fount any error or if it worked wine.

Comment: @ M. Deinum      I just uploaded my project in github. Please look if it would help to see the whole project.       https://github.com/gurpreetKharoud/ProjectDemo.git

Comment: @LynAs sir this is new project i created. a simple one. Still same issue.. error 404

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found the problem. When i wrote @ComponentScane on top of my MvcConfiguration class it worked and pages are displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I found the problem. When i wrote @ComponentScan on top of my MvcConfiguration class it worked and pages are displaying.